# TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jasmine

- I am trying to run jasmine test cases for my typescript file but its not running...
- can you tell me how to fix it...
- providing my code below...
- but when its converted to js its running..
- and I am facing one more error in that...

TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined

- working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/om4pc7s8/1/

- not working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/h6ck42kx/3/

```
describe("Our data array", function() {
  it("has four items", function() {
    var example = new Example();
    expect(example.players()).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

Comment: I get `options is not defined` in the second Fiddle... Not the error you talk about.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thanks for your reply... in the first fiddle I see this error in the fiddle TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined   in the second fiddle not sure how to run

Comment: In the first Fiddle, `options` is not defined too.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette can you tell me how to add...not sure how to do :(

Comment: I'm not familiar enought with Jasmine... I just can say that `options` is defined nowhere. It should be an object with a couple attributes... Something like `var options = {model: {SWIMMINGumentName: "SomeValue here", SWIMMINGumentMobile: "SomeValue here", SWIMMINGumentlength: "SomeValue here"}}`